# Mysqld Randomly stops running

Tags: mysql

Mysqld randomly stops running and I'm not sure what to check or what I should be looking for to see why it's randomly crashing.

I'm using:

```
AWS EC2
Ubuntu - 9.10
MySQL - 5.1.37
```

There is nothing located within the:

```
/var/log/mysql folder
```

and

```
/var/log/mysql.log & mysql.err
```

have nothing in them.

Any ideas?  Thanks all,

Justin

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked 
`/var/log/daemon.log`?

Sometimes I see useful information in there.

I have Ubuntu on AWS and I have under /var/log

```
-rw-r-----  1 mysql     adm        0 2010-09-09 11:31 mysql.err
-rw-r-----  1 mysql     adm        0 2010-09-16 06:32 mysql.log
```

and under /var/log/mysql

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql adm     0 2010-09-16 06:32 error.log
```

If you have a custom `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I would check that against the ubuntu default before doing anything drastic.

As a second idea, if you installed from packages, I would try backing up the database using mysqldump and reinstalling the package with `apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1` and `apt-get install mysql-server-5.1`.